# Is there a native OS X app like WorkRave?

Tags: productivity, rsi

I'd like a (preferably free) break reminder app that's native to OS X. Does anyone know of such a tool? There's [WorkRave](http://www.workrave.com/) for Windows and Linux.

Comment: http://alternativeto.net/software/workrave/?platform=mac

Comment: The #1 thing I hate about stack exchange is how they keep closing useful questions about application requests.

Answer (score 4):

You can use [20 Cubed](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/20-cubed/geghmabifcdlkmpnkapfefbbfaonhcef) or [Timout](http://timout.kramolis.cz/) for example.

There is also an app called "Be Healthy" and [iRest](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/irest/id428912146?mt=12). I just use 20 Cubed and Timout, they're pretty cool.

Comment: I just found that Timeout free is now available in App store and my initial test shows it is very similar to Workrave: http://www.dejal.com/timeout/ (good enough for me)